# Setting multiple styles for sections

Tags: sectioning, sectsty

I'm trying to style my section headers using `sectsty`, but I can't seem to apply more than one style. This is my code:

```
\sectionfont{\sectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-1ex}{0.1pt}}
%\sectionfont{\fontsize{30}{40}\selectfont}
```

If I uncomment the last row, it completely negates that first row. How can I both apply a rules to sections, AND change the font size? Also, how can I do this differently for each section (`section`, `subsection` and `subsubsection`)?

PS: I can't seem to find any documentation on `\fontsize`, am I using it correctly?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! With `titlesec` you can use `\titleformat{\section}{...}` inside the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\sectionfont` will overwrite the default setting AFAIK, so the latter one will make the former one useless. You should put them in the same `\sectionfont`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{30}{40}\selectfont\sectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-1ex}{0.1pt}}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
Lorem lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

A documentation on the `\fontsize` command can be found on [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Arbitrary_sizes).

Comment: Oh yeah I tried this, but in another order: `\sectionfont{\sectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-1ex}{0.1pt}\fontsize{30}{40}\selectfont}` and this doesn't work at all. How come? Thanks btw :)!

Comment: @Zorobay (1) You want the rule to be below, right? So you need to add `\fontsize...` _before_ it. I also think this is pretty strange. (2) If my answer helps, please mark your question as resolved by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer.